# How is this formula of the speed of sound derived?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, acoustics, speed

$$c^2 = \frac{n}{m} \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial n^2}$$

where

$U$ = vacuum energy density as a function of the quasiparticle density

$n$ = quasiparticle number density

$m$ = bare mass of quasiparticle